# Iphone returns photo data in different way

Tags: ios, vcf-vcard

I have import contacts to Iphone using CardDAV.

An strange thing happened here for the Photo attribute.

I sent Photo data to Iphone this way,

```
PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPG: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`
```

and so on .....

While Iphone return it in this way,

```
PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG;X-ABCROP-RECTANGLE=ABClipRect_1&0&0&160&160&ke51PoQcz6s21p/Tl7rZyw==:
 /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QCARXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABAEaAAUAAAABAAAAPgEbAA
 UAAAABAAAARgEoAAMAAAABAAIAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAATgAAAAAAAABgAAAAAQAAAGAAAAABAAOg
 AQADAAAAAQABAACgAgAEAAAAAQAAAKCgAwAEAAAAAQAAAGoAAAAA/9sAQwABAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ
 EBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB/9sA
 QwEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ
 EBAQEBAQEBAQEB/8AAEQgAagCgAwERAAIRAQMRAf/EAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgME
 BQYHCAkKC//EALUQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCsc
 EVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0
 dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1t
 fY2drh4uPk5ebn6Onq8fLz9PX29/j5+v/EAB8BAAMBAQEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkK
 C//EALURAAIBAgQEAwQHBQQEAAECdwABAgMRBAUhMQYSQVEHYXETIjKBCBRCkaGxwQkjM1LwFW
 Jy0QoWJDThJfEXGBkaJicoKSo1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5
 eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2u
  and so on .....
```

I need to compare the image and i am unable to do this due the photo data return by IPhone.
Note: Every time Iphone return the photo data different while image is same.

Any body knows what way Iphone is using to transform Image.

Answer (score 1):

The client is just adding proper folding as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2426#section-2.6

In other words, you are not supposed to have lines longer than 75 characters in a vCard. You need to fold those.